# Riemann sums and integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If the Riemann sums of a function $f$, defined on an arbitrarily tagged partition $P$, are positive, then will the integral also be positive for any arbitrary tagged partition whose norm is bounded?

Comment: If the function is integrable, yes. Your hypothesis   implies that $f$ is positive everywhere. If $f$ is integrable, the integral is then necessarily positive. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374600/use-the-concept-of-baire-category-to-prove-that-the-upper-integral-of-a-positive) for example. (Or argue using the fact that the set of points where a bounded, integrable function is discontinuous has measure zero; $f$ will then have at least one point of continuity. The result follows easily from this).

Comment: In the above, I assumed you meant to ask "will the integral also be positive?".

Comment: Can this not be argued using more elementary methods,perhaps from the definition itself ?
More precisely,
If $S(f;\dot(P))$ is the Riemann sum on any arbitrarily tagged partition $\dot(P)$ of $[a,b]$ ,such that $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists \delta_{\epsilon}>0$,such that if $\|\dot(P)\|<\delta_{\epsilon}$,then $|S(f;\dot(P))-\int^b_a f|<\epsilon$.
Using this if we fix $\epsilon:=\frac{S}{2}$,where $S$ is $S(f;\dot(P))$,then for a certain $\delta_{\epsilon}$,such that if $\|\dot(P)\|<\delta_{\epsilon_{0}}$,then$ 0<\frac{S(f;\dot(P))}{2}<\int^b_a f$.
Can such an argument suffice ?

Comment: Admittedly,this argument is inspired from a similar question in continuity.Hence the doubt regarding the validity of its usage.

Comment: I'm not following your argument. It seems off...  But, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360264/let-fa-b-to-mathbb-r-be-riemann-integrable-and-f0-prove-that-int-abf) is another relevant post. This post and the linked posts theiren (in particular, the first answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357472/let-fa-b-to-mathbb-r-be-riemann-integrable-and-f0-prove-that-int-abf) contains arguments  more direct than those I mentioned in my first comment.